How can I build an animate, increasing image size with motion frame?
I'm trying to build an animate like Neurable https://www.neurable.io/
You can see this animate in the Header and a little bit below, in the image of the maintainer. Basically, the image has a initial scale 0.8 and when the target reach 0.5 of the view port, the image becomes grow progressively until scale 1.0.
This application was built with Next.js
I've already try this way, but the image stay static with scale 0.8
"use client";

import Image from "next/image";
import "./about.scss";;
import { useRef } from "react";
import { useScroll, motion } from "framer-motion";

const About = () => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll({
    target: ref,
    offset: ["0 0.5", "0.5 0.5"],
  });

return (
<motion.div
         ref={ref}
        initial={{ scale: 0.8 }}
        animate={{
          scale: scrollYProgress,
          transition: {
            duration: 1,
          },
        }}
      >
        <section
          className="test"
          style={{
            width: "100%",
            height: "100vh",
            minHeight: "262px",
            paddingTop: "96px",
          }}
        >
          <Image
            src="/about.svg"
            alt="about_people"
            width={0}
            height={0}
            style={{
              objectFit: "cover",
              width: "100%",
              height: "100%",
              margin: "auto",
            }}
          />
        </section>
      </motion.div>
)
}



and if I take off the initial attribute, it works, but the image begins with scale 0 and it is not the animate that I need.
<motion.div
        ref={ref}
        style={{
          scale: scrollYProgress,
        }}
      >
        <section
          className="test"
          style={{
            width: "100%",
            height: "100vh",
            minHeight: "262px",
            paddingTop: "96px",
          }}
        >
          <Image
            src="/about.svg"
            alt="about_people"
            width={0}
            height={0}
            style={{
              objectFit: "cover",
              width: "100%",
              height: "100%",
              margin: "auto",
            }}
          />
        </section>
      </motion.div>
    </>
  );
};

export default About;


Hey @renan-frança  have you tried this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/78474466/8997321

Explaination:
Framer-motion will automatically animate to the values in animate if they're different from those defined in style or initial. The useScroll hook returns a motion value that doesn't re-render the state. (think about motion-values as an equivalent to refs in React). The main goal here is to control the animation ourselves.
Solution:
You're looking for an animation based on the transformed motion value you provide in the animated component's style field (not the initial/animate field itself).
// For a smooth animation:
// interpolate the raw scrollYProgress with the spring engine.
const smoothScrollYProgress = useSpring(scrollYProgress)

// Transform scrollYProgress to the desired scale (starts from 0.8, ends at 1.0).
const scale = useTransform(smoothScrollYProgress, [0, 1], [0.8, 1])

return <motion.div ... style={{ scale }}>...</motion.div>

Here's a working component: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/affectionate-cerf-ll9lyq
Read more about useTransform in the documentation: https://www.framer.com/motion/use-transform/

It turned this way...
I do not understand exactly, the interaction between offset and the scale within useTransform(), but it worked like the example
"use client";

import Image from "next/image";
import "./about.scss";
import { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useScroll, motion, useTransform, useSpring } from "framer-motion";

const About = () => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll({
    target: ref,
    offset: ["0, 1", "0.5, 1"],
  });

  const smoothScrollYProgress = useSpring(scrollYProgress);

  const scale = useTransform(smoothScrollYProgress, [0.5, 1], [0.5, 1]);

  //Responsive motion frame

  const [styleR, setStyleR] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      const handleResize = () => {
        console.log("TAMANHO DA TELA", window.innerWidth);
        if (window.innerWidth >= 1024) {
          setStyleR({
            scale,
            transition: "ease-in 0.1s",
          });
        } else {
          setStyleR({});
        }
      };

      window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);

      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
      };
    }
  }, []);

 return (
 <motion.div style={styleR}>
          <section
            style={{
              width: "100%",
              paddingTop: "64px",
              height: "100vh",
              minHeight: "262px",
              backgroundColor: "#143933",
            }}
          >
            <Image
              src="/about.svg"
              alt="about_people"
              width={0}
              height={0}
              style={{
                borderRadius: "4px",
                objectFit: "cover",
                width: "100%",
                height: "100%",
                margin: "auto",
              }}
            />
          </section>
        </motion.div>
)
}

